# Deploy smart-contract using nodejs

Tags: solidity, nodejs, solc

I am trying to follow the following example.

http://hypernephelist.com/2016/12/13/compile-deploy-ethereum-smart-contract-web3-solc.html

But I get the following error. Can anybody show me what is wrong in my code? Thanks.

```
$ cat contracts/HelloWorld.sol 
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;
contract HelloWorld {
  function get() public pure returns (string retVal) {
    return "HelloWorld!!";
  }
}

$ cat test.js 
const fs = require('fs')
const input = fs.readFileSync('contracts/HelloWorld.sol', 'utf8');

const solc = require('solc')
const output = solc.compile(input, 1);
const bytecode = output.contracts[':HelloWorld'].bytecode;
const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':HelloWorld'].interface);

const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3('ws://localhost:8546');

web3.eth.getAccounts().then((accounts) => { 
  const testContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
  testContract.deploy({
    data: "0x" + bytecode,
  })
    .send({from: accounts[0], gas: 4700000})
    .then((instance) => {
      console.log(`Address: ${instance.options.address}`);
    })
    .catch(console.log);
});
$ node  test.js 
connection not open on send()
(node:11309) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connection not open
    at WebsocketProvider.send (/Users/pengy/linux/test/gnu/geth/bin/Hello-Ethereum/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/src/index.js:211:18)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/pengy/linux/test/gnu/geth/bin/Hello-Ethereum/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/src/index.js:196:19)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:466:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:267:5)
(node:11309) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11309) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: You are parsing abi twice!

Answer (score 2):

You're parsing the ABI twice.

```
const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':HelloWorld'].interface);
```

and here

```
const testContract = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(abi));
```

just change the second line and remove the `JSON.parse` the error gonna be solved.

But consider that if you're using web3 1.0 (which come by default if you install the package now) that code wouldn't work properly. The syntax is different and you might need to change it properly:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:8545");

web3.eth.getAccounts().then((accounts) => { 
  const testContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
  testContract.deploy({
    data: "0x" + bytecode,
  })
  .send({from: accounts[0], gas: 4700000})
  .then((instance) => {
    console.log(`Address: ${instance.options.address}`);
  })
  .catch(console.log);
});
```

Comment: I still see errors. See the new edit. Do you know what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: it's quite obvious the error. the connection is not open. Are you sure that `'ws://localhost:8546'` is the right address / port and its listening on websocket? If not it won't work. If you use ganache-cli the default address is the one mentioned in my post

Comment: OK. I changed 8546 to 8545. Then, it seems to work `$ node test.js 
Address: 0x4F5818ffD21b1eb122Fb1517117bC15a5c4F5EC8`. Why the program does not terminate? What should I expect from this program?

Comment: The expectation is the contract address, and you're getting it. So it means it has been deployed correctly and your received the address back. The you can use `web3` to invoke your contract.

Comment: If I want to run execute the contract, how to do it?

Comment: I told you already, you cam use `web3` to invoke the contract. Please read the documentation https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html and if you have a specific problem ask another question.

Comment: The documentation there is outdate (it says `This documentation is work in progress and web3.js 1.0 is not yet released!`). I don't know what to learn and what not to learn.

Comment: is not outdated! The web3 1.0 is beta version and is the one that will be installed by default at the moment and is the one that the post refer to. If you want to use the previous version ( 0.2x.x ) then go here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API